# Change color button in Kivy

Tags: button, colors, kivy

First of all i'm not a professional programmer i'm just an hobbyist using code to make some stuff to work (not always).
I'm using Kivy at the moment to make a simple app and can't figure out how to change the color of a button to the color i really want. I've spent some time on the page, looked stackoverflow but still can't manage it...
Here's a bit of code. I use background_color to change the color and i understood i should use background_normal to set the "white color" (but i don't want the rest to be white...) and i don't know where to change background_color... Same question for when it's pressed.

It's alright for Label, this works :)

Other other small question. To get my rgb i divided all the color by 255 to get a value between 0 and 1, is it the correct way or they could be something more precise? 
Thanks !

```
BoxLayout:
padding: 10
spacing: 10
orientation: 'vertical'
Label:
    text: "Jouer avec les verbes \nirréguliers par :"
    color: 1,1,1,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.99, 0.65, 0.07, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spacing: 10

    Button:
        text: "L'infinitif"
        size_hint: 1, 1
        background_color: 0.81, 0.27, 0.33, 1

    Button:
        text: "La traduction \nFrançaise"
        size_hint: 1, 1
```

Comment: For the rgb just you adobe kuler its free

Answer (score 2):

I found something that might help you:

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html

```
background_color
```

Added in 1.0.8
Background color, in the format (r, g, b, a).

This acts as a multiplier to the texture colour. The default texture is grey, so just setting the background color will give a darker result. To set a plain color, set the background_normal to ''.

The background_color is a ListProperty and defaults to [1, 1, 1, 1].

Hope this is usefull, but next time search a little more ;)

**Found this on SO**

The problem is that Button.background_color really works as a kind of tint, not just a block colour. Since the default background is a grey image (the one you normally see if you make an unstyled button), what you end up seeing is a red tint to that grey image - which comes out as the dark red you observe.

You can get the behaviour you want by replacing the background image to just one that's plain white (it doesn't have to be more than a few pixels), or by otherwise playing with the background_normal and background_down properties. When your background_color tints the new pure white image, you get the pure red you're after.

And if thats not enough you can always watch this vid:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahx9RWqQNgg

Comment: Thanks, but i've read this i spent hours on this doc :) What i don't understand is how implement the background_normal to ". Where to put it is my question ? :(

Comment: I can change the color, but as the default texture is grey it makes darker result. My question is how to set the default texture to white for this particular button. I understand it's supposed to be acheived by playing with background_normal, but this, i didn't manage...

Comment: Just take a look at the video, the guy is doeing what i think you want to do.

Comment: Yes i've seen the video too, but again, you can't have the color you want, in the code i've written i use background_color: 0.81, 0.27, 0.33, 1 but it's as on the video,  it adds this color over a grey texture, so you don't have the color you want. What i would like is to be able "for this particular button" and not the other ones, to change the grey texture to white and also the blue one when you press to white so i can put my own color.

Comment: Have you found the background_normal property of a button

Comment: Unfortunatly no, i've found it in the doc yes, but i don't know how to use it :) (Btw, thanks for the help!)

Comment: Np, i think you can to it the same a the background_color

Comment: http://www.codedisqus.com/7JQHeXXkjP/changing-background-of-a-button-to-a-different-shape-and-styles-like-shadow-effect-etc-in-kivy-python.html

Comment: Unfortuntaly no it doesn't work the same way. The explaination in the doc over the property of a button says it, and also explains, but i can't understand.

Comment: You have 2 options in this case, Use a backgroundimage (wich would be looking better), or 2 be playing with the background_normal property

Comment: No problem glad i could help, in one of the links i've but in the comment or awnser there is shown how it can be used